# sample example to export data to Excel, PDF, CSV and XML using Display tag in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, displaytag

I need to export table data to excel using display tag . I am using spring mvc.
Can anyone please explain me how to do this with sample example?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say Display Tag is getting old. Exporting binary data through a JSP tag library is not really the way to do things anymore.

Instead, you should have a look at the Spring MVC way to [serve dynamic Excel documents](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-document) which uses [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (sorry @danny.lesnik, so maybe you want to undelete your answer :-) ) or [jExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)